# Configuração dos programas continuam mesmo após terem sido desinstalados

Tags: linux

Sou novo no Linux e percebi que algumas configurações de programas continuam mesmo após terem sido desinstalados. Vou explicar. Por ex.: Instalei o Cairo Dock. Então para desinstalar usei o comando:

```
sudo apt-get remove cairo-dock
```

Depois usei o comando:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Até então tudo bem, mas acabei instalando novamente o esse dock e quando cliquei em abrir, ele permaneceu com todos os programas que haviam antes de eu desinstalá-lo. Teria algum outro comando de desinstalar por completo? Outra coisa que achei estranho foi que depois de desinstalar o Cairo Dock, instalei outro dock e para minha surpresa, ao desinstalar também esse outro dock, ele permaneceu ativo, pois esqueci de sair dele.

Como faço para que os programas sejam totalmente desinstalados?

Configurações do meu Linux:

> DISTRIB_ID=LinuxMint DISTRIB_RELEASE=18.2 DISTRIB_CODENAME=sonya
>   DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Linux Mint 18.2 Sonya" NAME="Linux Mint"
>   VERSION="18.2 (Sonya)"

Comment: A resposta abaixo não resolveu? Sempre resolve quando utilizava este comando.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tente o seguinte:

```
sudo apt-get purge cairo-dock
```

O comando `purge` faz a mesma coisa que o `remove`, mas alem de remover os pacotes instalados do programa citado, também remove todas as configurações deixadas por ele.

Comment: Obrigado Articuno.